# BenQ SW271 + Spyder5PRO = 99% sRGB and 77% AdobeRGB

Tags: color, srgb

I recently bought Benq SW271. After creating a profile via Spyder5PRO turns out that the color space coverage for this display is just 99% or sRGB and 77% for AdobeRGB.

I am very curious if anyone of you uses similar setup and what are your results? Below I attach screens from Spyder5PRO overview screen.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What ICC profile are you using?

Comment: Also, what contrast/brightness/color settings on the monitor itself? These could be limiting the gamut if set to extremes....

Comment: have you changed the setting so that the graphics card is really using 10 bit per color to speak with the monitor? the default setting in windows is 8 bit per color and is not detecting 10 bits automatically. you have to activate this manually and then you should also get more colors

Answer (score 2):

The BenQ SW271 should be covering a much wider gamut than your results.

[This review at ephotozine.com](https://www.ephotozine.com/article/benq-sw271-4k-monitor-review-32232) states the following:

> The SW271 features a thin bezel and offers 99% AdobeRGB, 100% sRGB, 100% Rec.709, plus a High Dynamic Range (HDR) mode.

It's unclear if those are test results or specifications.

At [Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/benq-sw271-27-inch-professional-monitor,5785-4.html) the SW271 was actually tested to cover all of the above claimed color spaces.

The monitor is only one link in the color management chain, though. If the video card or the Spyder5PRO application is converting everything to fit in the sRGB color space before sending it to the monitor, the areas of Adobe RGB not also contained in sRGB space will not be sent to the monitor and the measurement using Spyder5PRO will reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a BenQ BL2711U and calibrating it with a Spyder 4 Elite.
My numbers are:
sRGB: 100%
Adobe RGB: 81%
NTSC: 78%

When calibrating, I initially chose the "wide gamut" option, but during the calibration, the app said that my monitor was not wide gamut.  I've never been truly happy with the Spyder.  Maybe I should have gotten the ColorMunki instead.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the brightness of your display will increase the gamut.  Do that to make the display cover more of the Adobe 98 colorspace

Comment: Is that always, universally the case? I would suspect some monitor models to do the opposite and clip the gamut if cranked up too bright ....

Comment: This is just physics,  so yes it is always the case.  a 600 nit brightness monitor will have a gamut much larger than a 100 nit brightness monitor given that phosphors are the same.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed you meant cranking up the brightness - in case of a monitor design that doesn't just increase the backlight intensity but eventually adds gain or level shifting when provoked, that could actually restrict the gamut....

Comment: Referring to the monitor the OP is asking about.  On that display increasing the brightness will increase the gamut of the display.